# Dictionary<string, List<String>> unexpected behavior

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

Summary of the Issue. In my program I create 5 keys in a dictionary and each dictionary key gets the value from a list. In the end I write the contents of the 5 keys in a file. If I use a list, write the values in the list, put the list in key1, clear the list to reuse it for key2 and so on, then in the end in the file all the 5 keys have the same values as the last key. If however I use a new list for each of the 5 keys, then I get in the file what I am expecting to get.

And now the code.

```
List<string> tempList = new List<string>();

tempList.Clear(); foreach (string item in PSD.labadvancedPathS) { tempList.Add(item); }
Debug.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n", tempList));
_iniFile.SetValueMultiLine("labadvancedPathS", tempList, false, true);

tempList.Clear(); foreach (string item in PSD.xmlCleanupBoolString) { tempList.Add(item); }
Debug.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n", tempList));
_iniFile.SetValueMultiLine("xmlCleanupBoolString", tempList, false, true);

tempList.Clear(); foreach (string item in PSD.rmiPathS) { tempList.Add(item); }
Debug.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n", tempList));
_iniFile.SetValueMultiLine("rmiPathS", tempList, false, true);

tempList.Clear(); foreach (string item in PSD.txtCleanupBoolString) { tempList.Add(item); }
Debug.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n", tempList));
_iniFile.SetValueMultiLine("txtCleanupBoolString", tempList, false, true);

tempList.Clear(); foreach (string item in PSD.xmlPathS) { tempList.Add(item); }
Debug.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n", tempList));
_iniFile.SetValueMultiLine("xmlPathS", tempList, false, true);

tempList.Clear(); foreach (string item in PSD.backupJobs) { tempList.Add(item); }
Debug.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n", tempList));
_iniFile.SetValueMultiLine("backupJobs", tempList, false, true);
.
.
.
_iniFile.UpdateIniFile(true);
```

Note: In each Debug.WriteLine() I am getting the expected output from the tempList

Now for the _iniFileSetValueMultiLine() part.

```
public class IniFile
    {
        private Dictionary<string, List<String>> settingsMultiLine = new Dictionary<string, List<String>>();

        public void SetValueMultiLine(string settingName, List<String> settingValue, bool updateTheIniFile = false, bool debugMessages = false)
        {
            if (settingsMultiLine.ContainsKey(settingName))
            {
                this.settingsMultiLine[settingName] = settingValue;
                if (debugMessages)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Found the setting " + settingName + " and putting in " + string.Join(", ", settingValue));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                settingsMultiLine.Add(settingName, settingValue);
                if (debugMessages)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Creating the setting " + settingName + " and putting in " + string.Join(", ", settingValue));
                }
                if (!messageWasShown)
                {
                    showErrorMessage(settingName + " was not found. Creating the setting " + settingName + " and putting in " + string.Join(", ", settingValue));
                }
            }
            if (updateTheIniFile) { this.UpdateIniFile(); }
        }

    }
```

Note2: In the Messagebox.show(), again, I am getting the expected output from the setting name and value

And finally, the part where I write to the file:

```
        public void UpdateIniFile(bool debugMessages = false)
        {
            List<string> whatToWriteToFile = new List<string>();
            foreach (string item in settingsMultiLine.Keys)//Enumerate through the multilined Settings
            {
                whatToWriteToFile.Add("[" + item + " START]");
                if (debugMessages) { MessageBox.Show("[" + item + " START]"); }
                foreach (string subItem in settingsMultiLine[item])//Enumerate through the values of the multilined setting
                {
                    whatToWriteToFile.Add(subItem);
                    if (debugMessages) { MessageBox.Show(subItem); }
                }
                whatToWriteToFile.Add("[" + item + " END]");
                if (debugMessages) { MessageBox.Show("[" + item + " END]"); }
                whatToWriteToFile.Add("");
            }
            foreach (string item in settingsSingleLine.Keys)
            {
                whatToWriteToFile.Add("[" + item + "]");
                whatToWriteToFile.Add(this.settingsSingleLine[item]);
                whatToWriteToFile.Add("");
            }

            File.WriteAllLines(iniFileFullPath, whatToWriteToFile);
        }
```

And this is where "something" happens and the 5 keys in the file are the same as the last one and also the messageboxes are showing the "wrong" info.

Thank you for reading me, please be gentle with me :)

Comment: You are storing the same list multiple times when you're adding it to `settingsMultiLine`. Create a new list each time rather than clearing the same list and adding that. (Note that at no time have you made a copy of the list, so of course it's the same one being used all the time.)

Comment: You should really be using a new list everytime. Each `SetValueMultiline` uses the same dictionary when you come to actually write everything to disk - it doesn't magically copy the values for you!

Comment: You need to add to the list in the value of the dictionary.  From : this.settingsMultiLine[settingName] = settingValue; To : this.settingsMultiLine[settingName].Add(settingValue);  If you are adding list of values then it is this.settingsMultiLine[settingName].AddRange(settingValue);

Comment: `List` is a class, which means it's passed by reference. So, everytime you're adding it to the Dic, you're adding a reference to the same object. When you use `new`, you're creating a new instance, that's why it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually expected behavior. As others have said in their comments, a list is a reference type, which means your aren't really adding the list to your dictionary, but rather a pointer to that list. Any changes you make to your list will be observed from all entities pointing to that list.

For reference I'd suggest reviewing reference types vs value types for a more in-depth understanding.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate and all the rest for the replies. See? This IS a gentle approach :)